# powering a split phase 220v appliance from a single 220v phase

Tags: electrical, 120-240v

I have a well water pump which works on 220v split phase and have a single phase 220v solar inverter. Can I just connect the hot wire with 220v to either wire and use the other wire as neutral?

Comment: What make and model is your solar inverter?

Comment: Presumably your pump is actually 240V 60 hz and your inverter might be 220, 230 or 240V 50 Hz.

Comment: Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4 and see if it clears anything up for you.

Comment: The inverters I have installed provide 240v leg to leg and are designed to back feed onto the power grid (neither side is grounded) if this is what your inverter output is it will be fine

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel its a mpp solar pip-5048gk series solar inverter and a hyundai HYWP1500G 1.5HP well pump